Как правильно работать с psql базой в асинхронном режиме | telegram bot | aiogram
Начал заниматься разработкой tg бота с базой psql и появился вопрос:
Как правильно работать с psql базой в асинхронном режиме, чтобы не делать много дорогих операций и рационально использовать ресурсы.
Всем привет
Недавно начал писать телеграм бота на aiogram 3. Есть потребность использовать psql базу. Сначала решил разобраться как работать в синхронном режиме и тут вроде все просто - создаем постоянное подключение в точке старта и для каждого запроса создаем курсор, который закрываем в конце запроса.
После того, как написал тестовый хендлер, решил попробовать положить бота через этот хендлер, что успешно получилось сделать используя 7-8 вызовов хендлера с запросом к базе за короткий промежуток времени. Ну, на синхронное решение в асинхронном боте я не рассчитывал. Перешел к изучению вопроса работы в асинхронном режиме и тут появился вопрос:
Как правильно работать с psql базой в асинхронном режиме, чтобы не делать много дорогих операций и рационально использовать ресурсы.
Почитал некоторые ресурсы, которые попадались в интернете, доку, спросил у гпт. Везде в примерах для каждого запроса создается отдельное подключение. Кажется, что это не очень рационально.
Мой типичный кейс в рамках одного хендлера - получить id пользователя из сообщения, с этим id сделать запрос к базе и вытащить из таблицы записи с этим id
Таких хендлеров около 10-12 штук
Буду рад примерам кода

Для этой задачи правильнее использовать asyncpg:


GitHub
Документация


Чтоб для каждого запроса не создавать отдельного подключения,
можно получать подключение из пула.
Создайте класс Database и через метод fetch_user_data производите асинхронные запросы.
Базовый пример:
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
import asyncpg

API_TOKEN = 'YOUR_API_TOKEN'
DSN = 'postgresql://user:password@localhost/dbname'

class Database:
    def __init__(self, dsn):
        self.dsn = dsn
        self.pool = None

    async def init(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(dsn=self.dsn)

    async def fetch_user_data(self, user_id):
        async with self.pool.acquire() as connection:
            result = await connection.fetch('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', user_id)
            return result

    async def close(self):
        await self.pool.close()


async def on_startup(dp):
    # Инициализация базы данных
    await db.init()


async def on_shutdown(dp):
    # Закрытие базы данных
    await db.close()


async def handle_start(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_data = await db.fetch_user_data(user_id)
    await message.answer(f"Данные пользователя: {user_data}")


async def main():
    # Создание экземпляра бота и диспетчера
    bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
    storage = MemoryStorage()
    dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

    # Регистрация обработчиков
    dp.register_message_handler(handle_start, commands=["start"])

    # Запуск бота
    await dp.start_polling(on_startup=on_startup, on_shutdown=on_shutdown)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = Database(DSN)
    asyncio.run(main())


Спасибо за ответ!
А что происходит, если запрос возвращает ошибку? Возможно ли будет в рамках этого же подключения делать запросы?
И еще один вопрос - наверное я не совсем правильно выразился про типичный кейс. Я хотел сказать, что операции не самые сложные - по типу select * from db where, но разные. Т.е где-то нужно будет вставить данные, где-то вытащить просто по условию where, где то с join.
Плюс проект разнесен по файлам и в идеале хотелось бы писать запрос внутри хендлера, чтобы не терялись среди кода нужные переменные, просто обращаясь к созданному в точке старта соединению

Если я правильно понял, то pool - постоянное соединение, в котором уже для каждого запроса вызывается connect. Есть ли какие-то ограничения по количеству коннектов в пуле и стоит ли беспокоиться за высокую нагрузку при условии, что максимальное количество одновременных запросов к базе будет не более 50-70

@Edmindo Если ошибка была обработана, и подключение все еще активно, вы можете продолжать выполнять запросы с тем же подключением. Однако, если ошибка была критической и привела к закрытию соединения, вам нужно будет получить новое подключение из пула. (в хендлере надо проверять состояние переменной user_data - if user_data is None: (в блоке if повторите запрос через метод fetch_user_data)). В самом методе fetch_user_data можно также отлавливать и обрабатывать исключения, адаптируйте его под Ваши потребности.

@Edmindo  "в идеале хотелось бы писать запрос внутри хендлера" - это моветон. Вообще классы для работы с БД бывают очень объёмными, Вы можете добавить в него все необходимые методы, например: async def add_user(self, user_id, user_name):. Если сами запросы у Вас объёмные, то можно вынести SQL-запросы в отдельные файлы и загружать их в вашем классе  Database.

@Edmindo Один вопрос — один ответ. Вы в вопросе написали, что проделали большую работу прежде чем обратиться на ruSO. В моём ответе было достаточно  указать название библиотеки, а ссылки на репозиторий и документацию позволяют Вам продолжить свои изыскания в правильном направлении. ... Дерзайте ныне ободренны  ... (М. Ломоносов "Ода на день восшествия на  всероссийский престол ее величества государыни императрицы Елисаветы Петровны 1747 года")

Спасибо за ответы)
Да, согласен насчет 1 вопрос - 1 ответ. Просто это вопросы, которые возникли в ту же секунду. Может кто-то воспользуется этим вопросом и в комментах заодно почитает про очевидные вопросы, которые тоже могут возникнуть

@Edmindo пул это не постоянное соединение, пул это постоянный источник настроенных соединений с ограниченным их количеством. В асинхронной среде важно контролировать количество подключений, пул как раз этим и занимается. Когда одна функция заканчивает использование соединения оно может быть передано другой функции. Пул управляет соединениями, выделяя свободное по требованию или открывая новое в пределах установленного лимита. Открытие соединения это довольно дорогая по времени и ресурсам операция. Работая без пула можно быстро исчерпать лимит подключений сервера
